# How to change the clock frequency of a STM32H753ZI

Tags: stm32, clock, clock-speed

just got a new MCU for testing and having a hard time changing its clock speed to the maximum (480MHz)

Using bare metals or directly manipulating the registers as I never liked the HAL interface.

What is throwing me off is usually STM32 in the Flash section will tell you which Wait State you need to configure the MCU for a Clock speed that you desire, however when it comes to this MCU it doesnt tell which Wait State for a the clock speed you want at all, instead it tells you the AXI peripherals.

Reference Datasheet: [STM32H753ZI](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00314099-stm32h742-stm32h743753-and-stm32h750-value-line-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) Table 17 Page 159

Comment: Just because you don't want to *use* the HAL doesn't mean that you can't answer your question by *reading* it.

Comment: Sorry, I am not following. Maybe I misworded that. I didnt want anyone to post a HAL solution to it as I am using the registers directly. Thats why I said that.

Comment: But you can *learn* how to use the registers directly by *reading* the code of the HAL.

Comment: Ah I see, I have checked it. Still didnt make sense to me. I need to know how it got those numbers. I dont see using HAL over a reference sheet as a viable source. For example in the HAL it made the WS = 0x4, WRHIGHFREQ = 0x3. Where did it get the 0x3 from? the table list the max for it at 0x02

Comment: Well, does what the HAL does work?  By all means compare to the documentation; but if what it does works, consider that it is an example which helps illustrate what the documentation is trying to say (or should have been trying to say)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that VOS0, which is required for 480MHz is not in the Reference Manual. I do not know why.

It is in the datasheet, however:
[image]

However, it seems to still lack 480MHz. Logic would dictate (and observing the trend of Table 17) wait states sort of increases linearly with clock speed for a given VOS according to the tables. So I am guessing you need 7 wait states at 480MHz, which I think is the maximum.

Also, I do not think you start up at 480MHz. From my perusal through the manual and datasheet, I am under the impression you have to start up at a slower speed and then switch to it (as well as switching other things as well). I could be wrong though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I dont see the VOS0 for 480MHz do you mind sending over the page number that you saw it? I mean I couldnt guess Wait state is linear to the CPU frequency, isnt the whole point to have these tables are to tell the end user what to configure probably without any hiccup, now I am gonna ask you how did you get to WS = 7 and yes it doesnt start up 480MHz

Comment: I found it. It's on the datasheet, not the RFM. I don't know why

Comment: oh I see, thats weird let me take a quick look

Comment: Well, it has VOS0 anyways, but still not 480MHz. And the linear trend I mentioned doesn't seem to quite hold up.

Comment: This is the most complicated Datasheet, yeah VOS0 is on the datasheet I see it now but in the reference sheet they call it Vcore boost!?

Comment: Then in the datasheet it says "refer to the table “Number of wait states according to
CPU clock (frcc_c_ck) frequency and VCORE range” available in the reference manual). " but doesnt state 480 MHz hahah what

Comment: Yeah. Kind of annoying.

Comment: Hmm, I found something interesting. In the datasheet Table 228 Document revision history it looks like they just added this "Changed maximum Arm Core-M7 frequency to 480 MHz." What the heck does that mean

Comment: @Leoc 480MHz only recently became available in a recent revision.

Comment: So Iam suspecting they forgot to update the reference sheet then. Looking at the reference sheet Iam saying the last update May 2017 where as the datasheet is April 2019

Comment: Your documents are out of date. Both of mine are April 2019. Datasheet Rev.7. RFM is Rev.6. 480MHz wait state still missing though.

Comment: Scratch that. Mine are updated. Didnt scroll down far enough

Comment: Oh, you know what? I think WRHIGHFREQ and the wait states we are talking about might only be for programming the flash. Not running code.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling that was it, however it then never explains how to increase the CPU clock frequency then

Comment: Scratch that. LATENCY is wait states for reading. WRHIGHFREQ is delay for writing.

Comment: I did get an answer from the STM32 Forums it self. It reads "The primary takeaway is that the AXIM while 64-bit wide clocks at half the core speed. The dual-ported FLASH is attached to the AXIM, and the wait states on the memory lines is based on the 200 to 240 MHz clock, and the power settings (higher voltage, faster memory).

 

One wait-state per 60-70 MHz, typically 4 WS for the CPU clocking at maximum

 

The only memory running at 400/480 MHz is the Cache and TCM, the bus width of the AXIM yielding similar bandwidth, but higher latency."

Comment: This isn't making sense. Under the register section, LATENCY is only defined up to 4 or 5 wait states, yet the manual says the MCU initializes with 7 wait states.

Comment: In the .h file where all the registers defines are kept the latency goes up to 15 WS which is why I posted this here

Comment: Yeah I think the documentation needs some catching up.